# Tag synonyms for [codeigniter] and [multithreading]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I would like to propose some more tag synonyms:

- [multithreading](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) (8) -> [threading](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/threading) (4)
- [codeigniter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter) (3) -> [code-igniter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-igniter) (2)

[thread-safety](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thread-safety) (5) also exists, it's not quite the same thing as [threading](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/threading), and so I would like to know what others think about whether or not the distinction is meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged the tags as indicated.

I agree that multithreading and thread safety are not the same. For instance, someone may have a post that calls an assynchronous method with a callback. That would be multithreading. Thread safety would come into play when on writes threaded code himself. Therefore they may be applied in different situations and are not synonyms.